# How to trigger a multi-step api transaction in the background?

Tags: ios, swift

In case it matters, this app was a 4.2 app but is upgrading to 5.0 with new functionality, including this.

In response to a *content-available* APN, I need to combine local device data with remote data before triggering a message to a third party. In the foreground, this process works, but in the background, it appears to freeze until the app is in the foreground.

I thought to resolve this with a DispatchQueue -- and that is getting me *a bit further* , but it is still not going all the way through.

When I receive my APN, I ensure it looks right (its a content-avaialbe notification and has a category), then fire off *loadPrediction*:

```swift
    // Tells the app that a remote notification arrived that indicates there is data to be fetched.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:
        @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            completionHandler(.failed)
            return
        }

        if aps["content-available"] as? Int == 1 {
            guard let category = aps["category"] as? String else {
                print("on didReceiveRemoteNotification - did not receive payload with category")
                print(String(describing: userInfo))
                return
            }

            switch category {
            case APNCATEGORIES.PREDICTION.rawValue:
                DataModel.shared.loadPredictions() {
                    completionHandler(.newData)
                }
                break
            default:
                print("on didReceiveRemoteNotification - received unknown category '\(category)'")
                completionHandler(.failed)
            }
        } else  {
            print("on didReceiveRemoteNotification - did not receive content-available in APN")
            print(String(describing: aps))

            completionHandler(.noData)
        }
    }
```

In loadPredictions, I request two pieces of data from the backend. **edit:** [I've read that you might want to start a different queue for each POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286939/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-dispatchqueue), so I've revised this next code block to its current form instead of just one queue:

```swift
    /** load prediction data for notification scheduling */
    func loadPredictions(_ callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("loading predictions")
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "loadingPredictions", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)

        queue.sync { [weak self] in
            print("loading predictions - in async task, about to getPredictionsDataFromFirestore")

            self?.getPredictionsDataFromFirestore() { [weak self] in
                print("getting Predictions Data from Firestore")

                if let error = $2 {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.dataFailedToLoad, object: error))
                } else {
                    let apps = $0
                    apps.forEach { app in
                        print("for each app - about to getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore")
                        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore_\(app.name)", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)

                        queue.async { [weak self] in
                            print("getting Notification Specification from FireStore")

                            self?.getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore(app: app) { [weak self] spec, error in
                                print("got Notification Specification from FireStore, about to post notification")

                                if(error != nil) {
                                    return
                                }
                                guard let spec = spec else {
                                    return
                                }
                                self?.postNotification(app: app, spec: spec)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // loadMergedForecasts($1)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.predictionsDataLoaded))
                }

                callback()
            }
        }
    }
```

They don't really need to be dependently related like that, but there's no point in doing the second one if the first fails.. If they both succeed, I should post a notification to my recipient in postNotification:

```swift
    /** notify third party app of available notificatiions to schedule */
    func postNotification (app: App, spec: NotificationSpecification) {
        print("posting notification")
        do {
            let notify = Data(app.notify.utf8)
            let localNotificationDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode(NotificationDetails.self, from: notify)

            if spec.p8 != "custom" {
                let token = localNotificationDetails.token


            } else {
                guard let bodyJSON = localNotificationDetails.body else {
                    return
                }

                guard let url = spec.custom_endpoint else { return }

                guard let methodString = spec.custom_method?.uppercased() else { return }
                guard let method = HTTPMethod(rawValue:methodString) else { return }
                if ![.post, .put, .patch].contains(method) {
                    print("app has unsupported method '\(method)' -- \(String(describing: app))")
                    return
                }
                guard var headers = spec.custom_headers else { return }
                if !headers.keys.map({ entry_key in entry_key.uppercased() }).contains("CONTENT-TYPE") {
                    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                }

                print("manually posting the notification with \(String(describing: bodyJSON))")

                let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "manuallyPostNotifications", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)

                AF.request(url, method:method, parameters: bodyJSON).responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print("Validation Successful")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let e {
            print("error posting notification to app \(app.id)\n\(e)")
        }
    }
```

NONE of these methods are on a View.

At first, there were zero cues and I dont know that I made it past the first loadPrediction. In its current state, the log looks like this when the app was in the background:

```
loading predictions
loading predictions - in async task, about to getPredictionsDataFromFirestore
getting Predictions Data from Firestore
for each app - about to getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore
getting Notification Specification from FireStore
```

**edit**: that's one additional line, but it doesnt represent any improvement for the additional queues.

It will complete and succeed if I foreground it (and he whole thing takes 1-2 seconds when fully in the foreground). But I'd like to do all my work now.

Questions:

I'm doing queues wrong. How do I not exhaust the queue that I am in?

Can anyone confirm or deny that this will work when the app is closed? I can see that *work is done* when the app is closed, but I haven't since gone back to test if the api calls work because I cant get it to work just in the background.

### addendum

revised code for current answer

```swift
    /** load prediction data for notification scheduling */
    func loadPredictions(_ callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("loading predictions")
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "loadingPredictions", qos: .default)

        queue.sync { [weak self] in
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            print("loading predictions - in async task, about to getPredictionsDataFromFirestore")

            self?.getPredictionsDataFromFirestore() { [weak self] in
                print("getting Predictions Data from Firestore")

                if let error = $2 {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.dataFailedToLoad, object: error))
                } else {
                    let apps = $0
                    apps.forEach { app in
                        print("for each app - about to getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore")

                        group.enter()
                        print("getting Notification Specification from FireStore")

                        self?.getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore(app: app) { [weak self] spec, error in
                            print("got Notification Specification from FireStore, about to post notification")

                            if(error != nil) {
                                group.leave()
                                return
                            }
                            guard let spec = spec else {
                                group.leave()
                                return
                            }
                            self?.postNotification(app: app, spec: spec) {
                                group.leave()
                            }
                        }
                        group.leave()
                    }
                    // loadMergedForecasts($1)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.predictionsDataLoaded))
                    group.leave()
                }
                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                    callback()
                    print("I am being called too early?")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and (added a callback to the final method call):

```
    /** notify third party app of available notificatiions to schedule */
    func postNotification (app: App, spec: NotificationSpecification, _ callback: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        print("posting notification")
        do {
            let notify = Data(app.notify.utf8)
            let localNotificationDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode(NotificationDetails.self, from: notify)

            if spec.p8 != "custom" {
                let token = localNotificationDetails.token

                callback()
            } else {
                guard let bodyJSON = localNotificationDetails.body else {
                    callback()
                    return
                }

                guard let url = spec.custom_endpoint else {
                    callback()
                    return
                }

                guard let methodString = spec.custom_method?.uppercased() else {
                    callback()
                    return
                }
                guard let method = HTTPMethod(rawValue:methodString) else {
                    callback()
                    return
                }
                if ![.post, .put, .patch].contains(method) {
                    print("app has unsupported method '\(method)' -- \(String(describing: app))")
                    callback()
                    return
                }
                guard var headers = spec.custom_headers else { return }
                if !headers.keys.map({ entry_key in entry_key.uppercased() }).contains("CONTENT-TYPE") {
                    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                }

                print("manually posting the notification with \(String(describing: bodyJSON))")

                let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "manuallyPostNotifications", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)

                AF.request(url, method:method, parameters: bodyJSON).responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print("Validation Successful")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }

                    callback()
                }
            }
        } catch let e {
            print("error posting notification to app \(app.id)\n\(e)")
            callback()
        }
    }
```

Realizing that my print statement wasn't inside the notify callback, I've revised it -- still not getting inside of the second firebase call.

```
loading predictions
loading predictions - in async task, about to getPredictionsDataFromFirestore
getting Predictions Data from Firestore
for each app - about to getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore
getting Notification Specification from FireStore
I am being called too early?
```

Comment: What do this print statements mean?  You use either `wait` or `notify`, not both. You can get rid of all of that weak self stuff because you can't create a retain cycle and you don't need the synchronous queue dispatch; the work will all be performed asynchronously anyway

Comment: So, you're right, my first approach was not printing useful information once we got to the leave() calls -- but I believe I have it now, and it is definitely calling inside of the notify block :(

Comment: and I now I got it.. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing off asynchronous tasks and your `callback()` will be executed before these tasks are complete.  Since `callback()` eventually calls the `completionHandler`, your app will be suspended before all of its work is done.

You can use a dispatch group to delay the `callBack()` until everything is complete.  The additional dispatch queues aren't necessary.

```
func loadPredictions(_ callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("loading predictions")

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() 
    print("loading predictions - in async task, about to getPredictionsDataFromFirestore")

    dispatchGroup.enter() 

    self.getPredictionsDataFromFirestore() {
        print("getting Predictions Data from Firestore")
        if let error = $2 {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.dataFailedToLoad, object: error))
        } else {
            let apps = $0
            apps.forEach { app in
                print("for each app - about to getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore")
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.getNotificationSpecificationFromFireStore(app: app) { spec, error in
                    print("got Notification Specification from FireStore, about to post notification")
                    if(error != nil) {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                        return
                    }
                    guard let spec = spec else {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                        return
                    }
                    self.postNotification(app: app, spec: spec)
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: DataModel.constants.predictionsDataLoaded))
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Paul, I am in a webinar but will implement this and accept later :)

Comment: after adjusting the brackets , I am still noticing that the line `dispatchGroup.notify {` raises the error `Missing argument for parameter 'queue' in call` -- this makes me think I should be adding a queue at the instantiation of the group

Comment: Sorry, yes, I typed it from (faulty) memory

Comment: I've revised my code and will add it to the OP so you can verify -- but it is not progressing any further

Comment: I am able to verify that you are correct (see the end of OP now) - but my implementation is not.

Comment: I have fixed the {} in my original answer; I left some in when I removed the queuing.  You need to ensure you call `dispatchGroup.enter()` before you start an asynchronous task and `leave()` before you exit the handler for that task. The number of calls to `enter` and `leave` must balance. `notify` executes when `leave()` has been called for all `enter()`s